# Problem with configuration of odoo for working with pycharm

Tags: configuration, pycharm, odoo

I have a problem with the configuration step of pycharm in order to work with Odoo 12.
I edited the configuration and set these parameters:

- In the script path field: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo-bin`
- In the parameters field: `--conf C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo.conf`

When I try to run I have the following error:

```
Usage: odoo-bin [options]

odoo-bin: error: unrecognized parameters: 'Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo.conf'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this error because of the space in the path try put it between two quotes:

```
        --conf="C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo.conf"
```

Comment: yes, i am sure                                                                                                                   Parameters: --conf="C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo.conf"                 script path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo-bin                                                                 now, when i try to run nothing is happening and when i write in my model: "from odoo import..." i have an error: unresolved reference 'odoo'

Comment: Hi it works when you do it like below

Comment: --conf=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\odoo\odoo-15.0\conf\odoo.conf